# Error in java on SPOJ

Tags: java, math, error-handling

**Problem**:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/EIGHTS/

Have to print kth number from beginning whose cube has 888 as last 3 digits. It follows a pattern:192,442,692,942,1192,1442,1692,1942,2192,2442,2692,2942 and so on.

**My Solution**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=p.nextInt();i>0;i--){
            int k = p.nextInt();
            int A[] = {192,442,692,942};
            int l = 0;
            while(l<k){
                if((l!=0)&&(l%4 == 0)){
                    A[0]+=1000;
                    A[1]+=1000;
                    A[2]+=1000;
                    A[3]+=1000;
                }
                l++;
            }
            System.out.println(A[(l-1)%4]);
        }
    }
}
```

SPOJ says **NZEC error**.

Help me figure out where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because you will be storing k = 2000000000000 in int which would be not possible and thus it is overflowing and might be storing a negative number you are accessing it for array index. Thus it is actually arrayIndexOutOFBounds problem. To check you can use try-catch for ArrayIndexOutOFBounds and print something. It will give wrong answer this time.

Comment: I have also tried using bigIntegers but it gives the same error

Comment: Here is the codepackage spoj;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eights {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=p.nextInt();i>0;i--){
            BigInteger k = p.nextBigInteger();
            k = k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            k = k.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(250));
            k = k.add(BigInteger.valueOf(192));
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Remove the first line "package spoj;". It is giving error. While submitting you don't have any package. Also try to optimize your algorithm because running a loop for 10^13 is not good.

Comment: Hint: You need to split for odd and even cases of K and try to make a general formula. Just try to write it down and you will visualize it.